# How to use the match expression of textMate to specify the scope of token highlighting in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use #regions in CSS. To make them even more pronounced I would like to style them in the settings.json of VS Code. The problem is, the #region shares a top-level textmate scope with normal comments. Now I wanna be able to say:

Apply these settings where textmate scope is "comment.block.css" && is not "meta.property-list.css"

From what I could gather, it looks like this should be possible, but I'm not able to find it.

It's kinda funny that I could use CSS selectors to select and style certain parts of my CSS.^^

Thank you in advance!

[The textmate scopes of the region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVqa3.png)

[The textmate scopes of the normal comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmkpp.png)

[The settings.json where I want to apply settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIRuY.png)

Cause I read that later statements in the setting.json override earlier statements, I tried to first style the #region with the shared scope (comment.block.css) and then get more specific and style the normal comment with the specific scope (meta.property-list.css). Kinda following the logic I would use in CSS, but no successes. The later style would always override the earlier one.

[Failed try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMTr8.png)

Comment: Note: You could make an issue ticket on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-textmate as a feature-request for a special textmate grammar to be added for matching `#region` comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight)